# CKEditor 4.7 Cannot read property 'on' of undefined, consulting and reseting with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a problem with CKEditor version 4.7.0. I'm using jQuery ajax to get and save information. The problem now is that Chrome v 58.0.3029.110 shows me an error in the console -  Cannot read property 'on' or undefined -, so I want to know how can I solve this or what kind of problem is. Here is my code:

```
function formService(id)
{
  clearFields();  // clear all the fields in the form

  // Show and hide form and record listing
  $("#areaForm").css("display", "block"); 
  $("#areaList").css("display", "none");

  if (id != 0) 
  {
    $("#id").val(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/'+controller+'/ajaxQueryRecord',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',   // to get a json object with all fields with information
        data: {id: id},
    })
    .done(function(json) {
        CKReset(json.content);  // A function below of this code
        delete json.content;

        // A global function that extract information and are assigned to their fields
        // in the form
        assign_JSON_to_Fields(json);  

        $("#btnSubmit").val("Update"); // Only to change the text of the button
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
} else {
    $("#btnSubmit").val("Add");
}//if
}//fn

// Clean all the fields in the form
function clearFields()
{
    $("#frmService input[type=text]").val("");
    $("#id").val(0);
    $('textarea').val(''); 
    CKReset('');
}//fn

// Function that reset content destroying CKEditor instance
// and create (replace) a new one
function CKReset(content)
{
    console.log(CKEDITOR.instances['content']);
    if (CKEDITOR.instances['content']) {
        CKEDITOR.instances['content'].destroy(true);    
    }//if
    CKEDITOR.replace('content');
    CKEDITOR.instances['content'].setData(content);
}//fn
```

[image]

Does somebody knows how to solve this detail? Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Why are you destroying and recreating the CKEditor instance? You just want to update the contents, so just use `setData()` whenever you need it and remove the `CKReset` function, which will only get you in trouble with so many `destroy()` and `replace()` functions..

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because in the Chrome (using only setData() ) each time I consult a record it turns more and more slow, and the console throws me information about the "items hidden by filters", for example, first consult are 3 items, then I go back to the list, consult new record, there are 6 items, then again 8, 17, 45, 100, 182, 509, etc., and for every time is more slow. And sometimes in first consult does not show the content of the record inside the CKEditor. So now is working good with my code, but it shows me that error I've published.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer of it, because the main problem was that CKEditor was not ready when I load ajax data, and didn't recognize the field of "content", then the console throw the error. But with this lines of code I don't have any problem to load content and the script waits until the instance of CKEditor is ready:

I had to delete this lines:

```
CKReset(json.content);  // A function below of this code
delete json.content;
```

And replace them with this lines:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['content'].on("instanceReady", function(event) {
   CKReset(json.content);
   delete json.content;
});
```

And the other code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use try/catch statement to destroy CKeditor :

```
console.log(CKEDITOR.instances['content']);
    if (CKEDITOR.instances['content']) {
       try {
           CKEDITOR.instances['content'].destroy(true);
       } catch (e) { }
    }
    CKEDITOR.replace('content');
    CKEDITOR.instances['content'].setData(content);
```